# Integration of Jenkins Job result in Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, integration

I'm currently improving the integration of Jenkins that we have in Gitlab CE 10.6.0.
For now, we had a webhook that trigger a pipeline in Jenkins. The job was executing fine, but in Gitlab we had only a pipeline shown has pending until it eventually failed, because no runner were installed.
I managed to improve the groovy script on Jenkins side to have the status shown in gitlab as well, as in the picture here :

[image: pipeline result in gitlab]

My problem now is that the parent job is still shown has pending, and still not running. I have not installed Gitlab Runner on my server (mostly because I'm not the administrator of it) and I don't think that could be an option.

Any idea on how I could have only the Jenkins part shown, and not the internal Gitlab part of the pipeline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, it appears that I had a gitlab-ci.yml file in my project that someone had comitted months ago but no one was using anymore...

So The solution was just to delete it to have the pipeline with only Jenkins steps